Trouble when creating PowerBI report via JavaScript Client Library
I'm trying to create a new PowerBI report via JS library.
I have a Microsoft Entra ID (Azure AD) Service Principal that assigned as admin to PowerBI workspace
Permissions
Also I have a dataset as a base for report creation.
I created a simple html+js page with the following code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Power BI Embedded Demo</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/master/dist/powerbi.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Power BI Embedded Demo</h1>
    <button type="button" id="save-btn">SAVE</button>
    <div id="reportContainer" style="width: 80%; height: 600px;"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
        console.log(models);
        
        var embedConfiguration = {
            type: 'create',   // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual, qna, paginated report and create
            datasetId: '838f7f0b-9ad6-4e9a-8924-cadb688f8cb8',
            groupId: '75c3eaf3-74cb-454b-aa86-d5480e66fded',
            embedUrl: 'My embed URL',
            accessToken: 'Dataset  access token',
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed
        };

        var $reportContainer = $('#reportContainer');
        var report = powerbi.createReport($reportContainer.get(0), embedConfiguration);
        console.log("Отчёт создан:", report);

        report.on("loaded", function() {
            console.log("Report loaded");
        });
        
        report.on("error", function(event) {
            console.error("Error while embedding report", event.detail);
        });

        let saveAsParameters = {
            name: "TESTREPORT"
        };
        
        report.saveAs(saveAsParameters).then(function (savedReport) {
            console.log("Saved!");
            console.log("Report info", savedReport);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error while saving report:", error);
            console.error("Error details:", error.body);
        });;

        let isReportSaved = report.isSaved().then(function (result) {
            console.log("Report saved:", result);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Trouble saving report:", error);
        });;
    });
</script>
</html>

In the result I was able to create report, but not to save it
Created but not saved report
As I saw from console, saveAs code hasn't been performed, but when I tried to click on save as button on the PowerBI embedded UI, (Top left corner: File -> Save as (Файл -> Сохранить как)) I received an error:
Error in console
To get embed token, I authenticated via Service Principal and sent request to the https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken
To get createReportEmbedURL I authenticated via Service Principal and sent request to the https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{my workspace}/datasets/{my dataset}
I'm expecting to have created report.

After trying to save the report via UI, I received error on UI
Activity ID9130d6f6-16fb-4d10-b6c6-d7579648e081
Request ID25d20acf-68a1-06ea-5c02-60e44ac60b19
Correlation ID81f1ee36-a399-73c0-f32f-efa6c2e355e0
TimeThu Oct 24 2024 15:36:31 GMT+0300 (Eastern Europe Daylight Time)
Service Version13.0.24488.44
Client Version2410.2.21363-train
Cluster URIhttps://WABI-WEST-EUROPE-E-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net

So after trying tones of things I found a solution.
Documentation says that I need embed token with access to dataset (semantic model in app.powerbi.com), but I does not say anything about the fact that I need to pass not only dataset id, but also workspace/group Id.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/generate-token
Here is the url:
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken
Here is the example body:
{
  "datasets": [
    {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }
  ],
  "targetWorkspaces": [
    {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }
  ]

}

I had performed authentication under service principal that was owned by master user account with Fabric Administrator role.
Hope it will help for somebody.
Also you can try to use older version of PowerBI Rest API and call another endpoint to get the access token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/reports-generate-token-for-create-in-group
